# Unable to mount location : Failed to retrieve share list from server: Invalid argument

Tags: samba

I have created an Active Directory Domain using Samba on Ubuntu
I can connect with Windows clients to the server, see the shares and create folders on the server.

However, when I try browsing the domain from the Samba (the AD server) I get the error :

```
Unable to mount location : Failed to retrieve share list from server: Invalid argument
```

I do have Winbind installed and running 
My `smb.conf` is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to connect exactly, which fails to retrieve list of shares?

In my case it was with the **caja** file browser, which uses **gvfs** as the backend for this.  It might not be samba's bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1828107

> The "trick" here is to try to connect to the server without invoking
> gvfsd-smb-browse. You can do that by accessing the server and share
> explicitly in Nemo:
>
> By mDNS host name ( hostname with a .local attached at the end ):
> smb://win10-host-name.local/share-name
>
> By ip address: smb://win10-ip-address/share-name

So once I entered an address that bypassed gvfs, I had access to my shares and files again, eg.:

*smb://negro.local/c/media/Videos*

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2435292